# Easy Way to Install RabbitMQ on Ubuntu Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, rabbitmq, erlang

Are there any clear, concise instructions for creating a Docker container with rabbitmq on Xenial that actually work?

I'm running rabbitmq in a Docker container and for some reason, installing it is a nightmare. Every time Erlang or rabbitmq has some update, one becomes incompatible with the other, and I get cryptic dependency issues. The [rabbitmq installation page](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html) does not provide step-by-step instructions, and every permutation I've tried has some sort of error (see below for the latest).

Dockerfile:

```
RUN  wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
RUN dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
RUN apt-get update
# Then install rabbitmq.
RUN echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian xenial main" | \
    tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list && \
    wget -O- https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/Keys/rabbitmq-release-signing-key.asc | \
    apt-key add -
```

Cryptic rabbitmq error:

```
=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 26-Jun-2018::03:04:55.163161 ===
    supervisor: {local,'Elixir.Logger.Supervisor'}
    errorContext: start_error
    reason: noproc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two answers posted here are admirable, but they don't answer the original question: provide a Dockerfile that installs compatible versions of Erlang and rabbitmq.

Below is such a solution (took much trial and error). It installs erlang 1:20.3.6 and rabbitmq 3.7.6. Changing the version should only require a change to the last line of this Dockerfile.

```
# Install Erlang + Rabbitmq
# Install the erlang downloader
RUN wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb && \
    dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
# Add the rabbitmq source list
RUN echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/rabbitmq/debian xenial main" | \
    tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bintray.rabbitmq.list && \
    wget -O- https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-release-signing-key.asc | apt-key add -
# Check which rabbitmq/erlang versions are compatible and isntall:
#       https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y esl-erlang=1:20.3.6 rabbitmq-server=3.7.6-1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install using the Erlang Solutions packages, `apt` will install the latest version of Erlang that they provide. At this time, that is version 21, which [is not yet supported by RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/which-erlang.html). This is why you are getting that Elixir error.

If you search the `rabbitmq-users` mailing list for the string `Elixir.Logger.Supervisor`, you will hit [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/TcXyFM-5SPM/discussion), which also explains [the cause of this problem](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/TcXyFM-5SPM/Y9cduCD9BQAJ).

To install the latest supported version of Erlang on Ubuntu, `apt` requires you to not only specify the meta-package version you want but also all of the dependencies with their versions. This is unfortunate, but can be accomplished by running this command:

```
apt-get install erlang-nox=1:20.3-1 \
    $(apt-cache show erlang-nox=1:20.3-1 | grep Depends | \
        tr ' ' '\n' | grep erlang | \
        grep -v erlang-base-hipe | tr -d ',' | sed 's/$/=1:20.3-1/')
```

See Roger's answer that involves pinning!

Comment: You can pin the version; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To pin the Erlang version to one that RabbitMQ currently supports, create `/etc/apt/preferences.d/erlang` containing the following:

```
Package: esl-erlang erlang*
Pin: version 1:20.3*
Pin-Priority: 999
```

(per https://askubuntu.com/a/926030/158095)

Comment: If I try this in my Ubuntu 16 VM, it still installs version 21 and I'm not sure why. The following Vagrantfile demonstrates a version that works - https://gist.github.com/lukebakken/251b964177a3c3a531ee48b665ffd4da

Comment: For some reason I have to separate out `erlang*` and `esl-erlang`. I'm not using the latter package so that could have been left out.

Comment: Weird, because I'm also using this in a Vagrantfile. I install `erlang` and `erlang-base-hipe`. Though, tbh, I've not tried it since 21.0 was released, it worked fine when 20.3 was out and we were targeting 19.x.

Comment: I had tried this and for some reason, it didn't work for me, maybe it's an issue with Docker. I've posted the answer that finally worked as another solution.